# No able to see my reputations

Tags: support, bug

I am a regular user of stack overflow... I am not getting my reputation notifications(on cup) when someone upvotes or downvotes me from today morning but can see my reputation goes increasing... Why this is happening?

Comment: @Glorfindel what is the solution for it? can you please help me

Comment: There is no solution (yet). You'll just have to wait :(

Comment: @Glorfindel ohh!!! that's site bug... thanks

Comment: Well, you could check your reputation tab: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation but it only works for a single site.

Comment: @Glorfindel notifications not working today... why so

Comment: They do work for me ... are you sure this bug is surfacing again?

Comment: @Glorfindel yes I am not getting notification for any comments since morning

Comment: But that's a different problem; this question is about reputation notifications. And you can see from my quick responses that those are working for me as well :)